# Adding a new field to nested subcollection in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

What is the best way to add a new field to many subcollection .
That new field is base on an existing field .(birthdate  to age)

Comment: "What is the best way" is always tricky to answer, as we don't know  much about your use-case. What is keeping you from implementing your use-case? Do you have a partial implementation already that you can share? Or if you've already implemented it completely, but are unhappy with the results: can you share your implementation and tell us what is not satisfactory about it?

Comment: i have some users data ,divided to a few sub collection . each sub collection represent a geohash. the data is fetched according to that geo hash and filter in the app according to other parameters.



i am doing some optimizations here , so in order to improve that query i need to add that field to all the user documents  .

long story short , fetch all sub collection of a document, and the update all documents in the subcollection